# How to wait for 1 second before continuing async thread?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to achieve here is for the thread to await at `FishData fishData = await Fishing().WaitOrCancel(cancelToken);` until a not null fishData is returned, else just keep on waiting and checking TryHook() again every 1 second.

I have also tried replacing the `await Task.Delay(1000);` with Thread.Sleep() but they just doesn't seems to work and instead kept on causing crashes. also tried InvokeRepeating and coroutines but everything got too messy and I'm not even sure I implemented them correctly.

```
    public async Task<bool> Fish(int ID)
    {
        reelingSuccess = false;
        FishingRodData fishingRodData = inventory.fishingRods[ID];
        if (currentCell.fill == CellFill.Water)
        {
            CancellationToken cancelToken = new CancellationToken();
            try
            {
                FishData fishData = await Fishing().WaitOrCancel(cancelToken);
                bool reelSuccess = await ReelingFish(fishingRodData.cycleTime, fishingRodData.tolerance, fishData.cycles, fishData.hits).WaitOrCancel(cancelToken);//, fishData.speed
                if (reelSuccess) print("successfully reeled in fish");
                else print("failed reeling in fish! better luck next time!");
                inventory.interactBtn.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
                inventory.interactBtn.onClick.AddListener(delegate { inventory.itrct(); });
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { print("fishing has been cancelled!"); }
            return true;
        } return false;
    }

    async Task<FishData> Fishing()
    {
        **await Task.Delay(1000);**
        print("try hook");
        FishData fish = TryHook();
        if (fish == null) fish = await Fishing();
        return fish;
    }
```

ps: forgive my english

EDIT: here's the TryHook Code
its basically trying to catch a fish based on probability which will mostly return a null, but once every few calls from `FishData fish = TryHook();` in Fishing(), it might return a fish.

```
    FishData TryHook()
    {
        FishData fish = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < fishLs.Length; i++)
        {
            fishLs[i].minValue = inventory.fishes[i].minValue;
            fishLs[i].maxValue = inventory.fishes[i].maxValue;
            fishLs[i].probability = inventory.fishes[i].probability;
        }
        int index = GetRandomValue(fishLs);//get random index in fishLs but based on probability instead of Random.Range()
        if (index != -1) { print("caught fish ind: " + index); fish = inventory.fishes[index]; }
        return fish;
    }
```

EDIT2: not sure if this is important, but this is how the Fish() is called.

```
    void Start()
    {
        itrct = new interact(Interact);
        fs = new Fish(activities.Fish);
        rf = new removeFront(RemoveFront);

        tryActivities.Add(new Func<bool>(() => activities.DoNothing()));
        //tryActivities.Add(new Func<bool>(() => activities.Fish(currentSlot.basicData.typeID).Result));
        tryActivities.Add(new Func<bool>(() => fs(currentSlot.basicData.typeID).Result));
        tryActivities.Add(new Func<bool>(() => activities.UseStove(currentSlot.basicData.typeID)));
    }

    public void Interact()//id of currently hold item
    {
        Debug.Log("interact");
        if (currentSlot != null && currentSlot.basicData.allID != -1 && TryPlaceOrUse())//check for hand activity
        {
            Debug.Log("successfully do in-hand activity");
        }
        else if (currentCell.objects.Count > 1 && currentCell.objects[^1].GetComponent<SpawnedObjectData>().allID != -1 &&
            tryActivities[(int)allBasicData[currentCell.objects[^1].GetComponent<SpawnedObjectData>().allID].myActivity]())//check activity infront
        {
            //await tryActivities[2];
            Debug.Log("successfully do in-front activity");
        }
        else Debug.Log("show emotes~ there's not hing to do ~~");
    }
```

Comment: What exact error do you get? "causes crashes" is not very informative, and .Net usually produces fairly good error messages that can help identify the error.

Comment: @JonasH do you mind showing me how to check the error messages?, becuase so far Unity just freezed up and I'm unable to click on anything with nothing on console either.

Comment: Freezing and crashing are not the same, which one is it?

Comment: @PalleDue I didn't know thery were different, sorry. After a google search I think it's leaning more toward freezing or unresponsive (similar to an infinite loop).

Comment: What exactly does `TryHook` do? Also, the first step to investigate *hangs* would be to break the program in a debugger and check the call stack. This can be more difficult when using async code, but it might still reveal something.

Comment: @JonasH I've never really used a debugger nor checked call stacks before, So I will give that a try. And about the `TryHook` code I've edited my post for you.

Comment: After a couple of trial and errors, I tried using unity's profiler and checking its callbacks from there, however, unity simply turn unresponsive and I'm unable to click on anything. This happens whenever `Fishing()` is called with the `await Task.Delay(1000);` line inside.

Comment: I would suggest reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). While the code posted by vhr should work fine in a regular c# program, it is possible that Unity has some restrictions on async. I would suggest trying to find some article on how to make a *timer* in Unity if you want to do something periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async Task<FishData> Fishing()
{
    while(true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        print("try hook");
        FishData fish = TryHook();
        if (fish != null) 
        {                
            return fish;
        } 
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var data = await Fishing();
// do what you want with your fish here
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but unity still crashes(freezes) every time `Fishing()` is called. Thank you very much for the reply tho